# Dynamic Keyword, C# and Interop?

Tags: c#, dynamic, interop

Ok, I am calling an interop dll which I have no access to. Here is the pseudo code:

```
dynamic myVariable = null;

firstInteropMethod(ref myVariable);
secondInteropMethod(myVariable); //Not by ref
```

The method signatures for the two methods are

```
firstInteropMethod(ref object someObject);
secondInteropMethod(object someObject);
```

The expected value is a double array of the definition

```
double[,]
```

Now the fun part. My original code gets the wrong results but no error. However, this code:

```
firstInteropMethod(ref myVariable);
secondInteropMethod((double[,]) myVariable);
```

Gives the expected results.

Using watches and type of statements I have determined that nothing changes between the two calls so what gives? Why would there be a difference and what would that difference be?

Comment: Could you show us the definition of the original methods?

Comment: What happens if you change `dynamic` to just `object` in the variable declaration?

Comment: You don't have `secondInteropMethod` overloaded, do you?

Comment: could you also elaborate on how the end value is wrong? is it unaffected by te first method or the second method? both? i sustect this could be a boxing issue..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This MSDN article on dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) explains why casting is needed for COM Interop when operations declare the parameter type as `object` and indicates that using the `/link:filelist` compiler option will allow you to define the COM method signatures as dynamic as well.

Comment: My question is not about whether I am sending it by reference or not but why a simple cast makes all the difference in the world when by all documentation it should not. And, IIRC, since I am using interop my parameters are not exactly passed by reference unless the method signature explicitly states otherwise due to marshaling yada, yada, yada.

Comment: @Synxmax The article I cited was in response to why a cast is necessary. The specific line in the article (under the COM Interop heading) states: "Many COM methods allow for variation in argument types and return type by designating the types as object. This has necessitated explicit casting of the values to coordinate with strongly typed variables in C#."